# Maven build task issue in Eclipse - StackOverflow and recursive call at DeferredTypeMap?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build, javac

[image]
Hi

Has anyone seen this recursive error stack trace before?!

I just went to build my project and got this....

Thanks

Leigh

Comment: The first line shows `The System is out of recources`... either out of memory ... threads etc. Is there a reason to run build within from Eclipse? Why not command or even better on a CI solution?

Comment: I'm going to move it into CI soon on GitLab as fortunately I just got chance to migrate old source code for my client from svn to GitLab!!!! This was to get a WAR built right now as usually it builds fine. I just migrated the core engine of the project to a new version and the vendor has never seen this (and you do not need to specify mem settings for the build either)

Answer (score 0):

OK

So some odd recursion seen in a core Java package here. I used **-Xss2M** to allow enough thread stack size for a successful build. I can honestly say I've never had to use xss!

(Java 1.8.0_151 btw).